# Error:CS1061: 'Encrypt' does not contain a definition for 'Encrypt' and no extension method

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, encryption, cryptography

I am developing using asp.net/c# and when trying to type this code:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(input_image);
this.Encrypt(input_image, output_image);
```

I faced a problem that is:
**'Encrypt' does not contain a definition for 'Encrypt' and no extension method 'Encrypt' accepting a first argument of type 'Encrypt' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

What I tried to do for solving this problem:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(input_image);
         this._Encrypt(input_image, output_image);

private void _Encrypt(string input_image, string output_image)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

and suddenly the error was removed! Is that solution right?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you're looking to encrypt the uploaded file, throwing a `NotImplementedException` will definitely **not** do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Jesse for your replied! Is that `NotImplementedException` is a useless in using?

Comment: It is likely useless for what you're expecting to have happen.

Comment: You've only posted snippets, which really makes it hard to help you. It looks like you're trying to do this in a *class* called `Encrypt` - you can't declare a *method* called `Encrypt` in a class which is already called `Encrypt`. I'd also strongly encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: You are right Jon! Thanks all!